# Fill numpy.darray with tuple skipping columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have a m x n array using `np.zeros([m, n])` and I want to fill some row (for example row 0) with a tuple that is returned. However I want to skip certain columns that should remain 0.

Now i have to repeat the function (or store them somewhere) and fill certain parts of the row.

Example with a function that returns a tuple of length 6

```
A[0,0:2] = someClass.someFunc(var1, var2)[0:2]
A[0,4:8] = someClass.someFunc(var1, var2)[2:6]
```

I fill the first 2 columns with the first 2 variables of the tuple, skip 2 rows and then fill the following 4 columns with the remaining part of the tuple.

Is there some way to achieve something like this:

```
A[0,0:2], A[0,4:8] = someClass.someFunc(var1, var2)
```

Skipping the need to repeat the function?

Comment: Why can't you do `t = someClass.someFunc(var1, var2); A[0,0:2], A[0,4:8] = t[:2], t[2:]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could concatenate those ranges with [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to simplify the left side -

```
A[0,np.r_[0:2,4:8]] = someClass.someFunc(var1, var2)
```